# Can we set a limit of editable excel rows and columns using PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I'd like to find a way to allow the user to see an excel sheet with max 1000 rows and a specific limit of columns too.  This [link](http://spreadsheets.about.com/od/excelformulas/ss/2011-05-14-excel-2010-limit-rows-tutorial.htm) shows a similar example of what I need (and why).

I developed a template with 1000 rows having data validation lists (one for each cell), and I don't want to let the user try to enter data manually after ending the 1000 data validation lists I set. This way, it would be great if PHPExcel could set a range of editable (or visible) rows and columns.
I tried to search in the documentation, but I couldn't find something for it (maybe I did a bad research)

Comment: First question to ask is how would you do it in MS Excel itself? One possible solution I've been requested for is to limit the visibility of rows/columns beyond certain limits, but that isn't implemented yet. Another option would be to set cell protection, but that would be costly in terms of performance and filesize

Comment: in fact, @MarkBaker, in the link I talk in my question there's an example doing this in excel, but I notice it's using VBA to do that. I couldn't test because my excel version is 2008 for mac and It doesn't have VBA... Anyway, I think it's not possible and I'll try to add a message in the cells 1000 for the columns I'm using in my template, informing the user that he should stop there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's not possible yet to set a limit of visibility for rows/columns, my solution was this:

First I set protection to the sheet, then I remove the protection of the cells I want to let the user be able to edit:

```
    $latestTemplateColumn = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn();
    $latestTemplateColumn++;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getProtection()->setSheet(true);
    $column = 'A';
    for ($row = 3; $row <= $maxRows; $row++) {
        for ($column = 'A'; $column != $latestTemplateColumn; $column++) {
            $cell = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell($column.$row);
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($column.$row)->getProtection()->setLocked(PHPExcel_Style_Protection::PROTECTION_UNPROTECTED);
        }
    }
```

This code starts in the row 3 until the $maxRow I set, and also until the last column that has data. This way the user can only enter data in the range I set.